# Evaluate the integral of $|\sin x|$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluating $$\int_0^\frac{π}{2} |\sin x| \:dx.$$

Shouldn't the answer just be $(-\cos x)_0^\frac{π}{2}$ since $|\sin x|$ isn't negative in that interval?

Comment: Yes of course! You are right.

Comment: Yeah, no doubt .

Comment: Yes, over $[0,\pi/2]$ you have $|\sin x|=\sin x$.

Comment: Alright I thought I was missing something since I didn't think it was supposed to be that easy

Comment: Everybody: it's `\lvert\sin x\rvert`, not `|\sin x|`. Compare: $\lvert\sin x\rvert$ and $|\sin x|$. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395119/4427

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^\frac{π}{2} |\sin x| \:dx$, the modulus just claims that $|\sin(x)|$ must be positive, which it is in the interval $[0\frac{\pi}{2}]$.
Bear in mind that the anti-derivative of $f(x)=\sin(x)$, whether positive or not it is $-\cos(x)$.

So the integral:

$\int_0^\frac{π}{2} |\sin x| \:dx=\int_0^\frac{π}{2} \sin x \:dx=-\cos(x)|^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0=0-(-1)=1$